# ANDROID: If Statement doesnt produce expected results

Tags: android

I have a database named tblclients with a column called email verified which produces either a 0 or a 1. 0 means unverified and 1 means verified. However implementing an if statement in android studio doesnt produce the expected results.

Here is my code:

```
    textfullname.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(ProfileActivity.this).getUser().getFirstName()+" "+SharedPrefManager.getInstance(ProfileActivity.this).getUser().getLastName());
    textCompname.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(ProfileActivity.this).getUser().getCompanyName());
    textEmailad.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(ProfileActivity.this).getUser().getEmail());

    int verification = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(ProfileActivity.this).getUser().getEmail_verified();
    if (verification == 0) {
        verifyemailad.setText("Email Un-verified");


    }
    if (verification == 1) {
        verifyemailad.setText("Email Verified");

    }

    int verifycolor = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(ProfileActivity.this).getUser().getEmail_verified();
    if (verifycolor == 0) {
        linearVerified.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_A700));

    }
    if (verifycolor == 1) {
        linearVerified.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green_A700));
    }

}
```

After implementing this code and running the code, i get a red background and Email unverified even though loggedin user is verified. Expected result must show green background with a Email verified text for verified users and red background with text Email unverified for unverified users.

Here is a screenshot:

[Screenshot of results regardless of email verification status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9pAG.png)

Can anyone help tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: `doesnt produce the expected results` ... what is unexpected about your current code?  We kind of need to know this in order to help you.

Comment: did you debug what is inside the variable 'verification '

Comment: May be you store verification  as String. it may create problem because you fetch verification as int.

Comment: if it were string there should be casting compilation error. or either he is converting the value inside get getEmail_verified method

Comment: Post UPDATED with screenshot

Comment: Email verification type is a tinyint in MYSQL and i have cast it as an int in android studio

Comment: can you share other related code?

Answer (score -1):

High chances is that your verification field is empty. You can try to print it out first after assignment or put an else statement to capture other unseen and unexpected results.

Comment: That is not possible given that all the database entries are assigned either a 0 or a 1. Plus if what you are saying is the case i wouldnt be able to display anything but in my case regardless of assigned number, the code is fetching 0 even tho my if statement commands the code to cast the emails as verified if the fetched number is 1. Hope you get me

Comment: Use comment feature